# PowerShell: Remove XML node from Visual Studio project file

Tags: xml, powershell, visual-studio

I'm trying to remove a node from a list of .vcxproj files using PowerShell.
Here's what I come up with so far:

```
function Delete-Properties {
    
    $projFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.vcxproj -rec
    
    foreach ($projFile in $projFiles)
    {
        Write-Output $projFile
        
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content $projFile)
        
        foreach ($PropertyGroup in $xml.Project.PropertyGroup) {
            $n = $PropertyGroup.Item('IncludePath')
            if ($n) {
                $PropertyGroup.RemoveChild($n)
            }
        }
        
        $xml.Save($projFile)
    }
}
```

And I'm confused why I'm getting this output:

`#text : ../include`

The console output is correct, that's the correct value from the correct element.
But I'm not sure why it's even printed and why I see no changes in the file.
The console output comes from here:

`$PropertyGroup.RemoveChild($n)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `RemoveChild` outputs `XmlNode`, so `$null = $PropertyGroup.RemoveChild($n)` should likely solve your problem. Unlike a C# method, everything that produces an output, if not captured or redirected becomes your function's output.

Comment: Also change `$xml.Save($projFile)` to `$xml.Save($projFile.FullName)`. This is necessary to ensure use of a full path in Windows PowerShell (no longer necessary in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)). See the first duplicate for details on what Santiago describes, and the second one for the full-path problem.